# How do suds cause water leakage and the machine to breakdown?

Tags: washing-machine

It seems like an old wives' tale, but I've got a quote [here](https://www.samsung.com/sg/support/home-appliances/how-to-maintain-samsung-washing-machine-after-use/):

> Regular detergents produce much more suds and can cause water leakage.

How do suds actually cause water leakage and the machine to breakdown? Anyone got a video capture or a diagrammatic explanation?

Comment: soap reduces surface tension of water ... normally, water will not flow through very tiny holes (unless under pressure), because of the surface tension

Answer (score 1):

Pour yourself a drink.   Use a fresh cold can of soda and a clear-sided glass. *Now, watch the interface between foam and liquid*.

As the foam falls, the liquid line rises.   That's because **foam is made of liquid**.

The reverse happens when you agitate soapy water.  Now the foam *rises* without limit, and reaches places it couldn't reach without foaming.  Once it is clear of the agitation, it settles back into soapy water.  It can do this unlimited, so it can pump a lot of water.

So it's not leaking, it's migrating.  You are using too much soap (or poor soap).

Detergent bottles are tricky these days.  They went to those goofy "scoops", which caused the caps to become very large.  Separately, they also made detergent much more concentrated.  The upshot is that **caps are no longer sized for 1 load per cap.  You need to read the instructions** and look at the very non-obvious graduation markings on the cap.  For instance the detergent I use, you use 1/6 to 1/3 of a cap.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer, except one point that if too much suds are formed the motor pump can cavitate as it tries to pump 'nothing' (foam).